# Rename column headers after given position in the file

Tags: pandas

I have been given data in a format that means there are some column headers, and some are unnamed.  When I import them as a table, I get "Unnamed: 0"... for the unnamed columns, of which there are hundreds.

I actually only need a subset, and fortunately they always start at the same column, i.e. column 325.

What I would like is to be able to rename only columns from 325 onwards, with "Result1", "Result2", etc for each column.  The number of columns varies from file to file, so I don't know exactly how many columns will need to be renamed, but each file has the results start at position 325.

I've tried renaming using

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed: ','Result')
```

However, this changes all columns without a header, of which there are hundreds. I just want to start at column 325.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
columns = df.columns.tolist()
new_columns = columns[:324] + ['Result' + str(i) for i in range(1, len(columns) - 324 + 1)]
df.columns = new_columns
```